# Compute cumulative (consecutive?) probability with a given size

Tags: probability

*So... I know that the answer is really simple, but at the moment I'm completely lost and that's why I'm asking for your help.*

The **problem** is the following:

I have a "coin" with arbitrary "selectable probabilities" for head and tail, and I want to compute the probability that I need to apply to the head, to obtain a series of sequences of uninterrupted heads with a length of expected value N.

For example, if N=5, what is **prob(head)** such that I obtain an average sequence of length 5 (like this H,H,H,H,H,T) ?

---

Second part:

Instead of a "uniformly distributed randomness", I would like to obtain a series of uninterrupted head sequences with a normal distribution ($\mu , \sigma$). How the probability of the head of the coin should change after each throw to obtain the normal distribution?

Thanks to everyone

Comment: What do you mean by an "average sequence of F,F,F,F,F"?  What might other possible sequences look like of which that was the average?

Comment: The normal distribution does not fit discrete distributions.  For example after $3$ tosses there are $8$ possible sequences, which can be summarised as $4$ possible numbers of "heads" [what you call  "faces"] seen.

Comment: Thanks for the doubts, I edited the question to make it clearer. Since I'm interested in sequences of uninterrupted heads (H), other sequences may look like this:
H,T; 
H,H,T; 
T; 
H, [...], H, T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the probabilities of heads on each toss are the same $p$ and independent of the other tosses, then you are looking at a type of *geometric distribution* where the probability of $n$ heads followed by a tail is  $p^n(1-p)$, with mean $\frac{p}{1-p}$.

So if you want the mean to be $5$ heads before the first tails, then you want the probability of heads to be $p=\frac56$.

If the probabilities of heads change with each toss then the probability of $n$ heads followed by a tails is $(1-p_{n+1})\prod\limits_{i=1}^n p_i$ and is $1-p_1$ when $n=0$.  You can adjust the $p_i$ to get any distribution on $\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$ you desire.

Comment: I'm still having difficulties understanding how to select $p_i$ as to obtain a normal distribution, but thanks for pointing me in the right direction with the geometric distribution and mean. That first part worked well in my testing

Comment: The normal distribution does not fit discrete distributions.

Answer (score 0):

After some days, a colleague came up with a solution for the second part (the normal distribution), so I'm adding this here for reference:

Given $\mu = N$ and $\sigma$, and being $y= e^{\frac{-(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$ with $x \in [1;2N]$, the probability distribution. Calling $y_N$ the normalized distribution (i.e. $y_N(x) = y(x)  / \sum_{i=1}^{2N}y(x_i)$ )

The formula is:

$p_i = 1 - \frac{y_N(x_i)}{1-CDF(y_N(x_i))}$

where $CDF(y_N(x_i)) = \sum_{j=1}^{i-1}y_N(x_j)$